# How to change the heading tag of the page-title from H5 to H1

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to change the [page title from h5 to h1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QTzHm2oCgv_irtqN0P55NUk0RNkDQWPS/view?usp=sharing) i tried to copy the

```
/inc/template-tags.php
```

into the child theme and made the edit to the function but its still loading the old template. I'm currently using the Constico theme.

[Example page link](https://beachtravel.tmmbuilds.com/beach-resorts/mauricia-beachcomber-resort-spa/)

Thank you!

I tried copying the

```
/inc/template-tags.php
```

file from the parent theme to the child theme and made edits but it didn't work as wordpress is saying the function is being called twice giving an error!

Comment: Don't copy the whole file just copy the desired function, rename it and change the hook priority.

Comment: Hi @MuhammadZohaib, thank you for your comment, could you please give me more explanation?

Here is the function i want to replace : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X5SlbWOV8ybj79krkR2y0rK2RgUpJBtu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Well its not an action or filter hook, so you'll have to override using template-parts or header may be. can you check if `constico_site_breadcrumbs()` this function is inside header file or template-parts?